# docker codeception unit tests run time is too long on Mac

Tags: docker, codeception

In our project for local env. we are using Docker containers for development and running test. And `vendor/bin/codecept run unit` is taking almost 7 minutes for devs who work from Mac, but only 17 seconds for devs from linux. Any idea what can cause the issue? I believe the issue is on some docker configurations on Mac

Comment: I think MacOS doesn't support cgroups (operating system technology that enables Docker to do what it does) so the slowness would be from how Docker for Mac works around that limitation (apparently Docker for Mac did or still does use a Linux VM under the hood).

Comment: Thanks, I also thinking it's because Mac do not support linux containers natively but using docker machine instead. Also I found http://docker-sync.io, will try it later, maybe it can help

Comment: Any updates on this? Did docker-sync helped?

Comment: no, we skip running deception tests locally, on Linux, all works great